# Query string form $_GET['value'] is not working as meta value in wp_query

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

Here is my code.How strange! if I put any static value replacing $s_string, it's working fine. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
$s_string = !empty($_GET['q']) ? sanitize_text_field($_GET['q']) : '';
$custom_fields = new WP_Query(array(
            'post_type' => 'post_type',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
        ));
        $fields = $custom_fields->posts;
        $post_ids = array();
        foreach ($fields as $post) {
            $post_ids[] = $post->ID;

        }
        if( count( $post_ids ) > 1 ) {

            $sub_meta_queries = array();

            foreach( $post_ids as $value ) {

                $sub_meta_queries[] = array(
                    'key'       => $value,
                    'value'     =>  $s_string,
                    'compare'   => 'LIKE'
                );

            }

            $meta_queries[] = array_merge( array( 'relation' => 'OR' ), $sub_meta_queries );

        } else {

            $meta_queries[] = array(
                'key'       => $post_ids,
                'value'     => sanitize_text_field( $s_string ),
                'compare'   => 'LIKE'
            );
        }
```

Comment: You haven’t defined `$s_string` anywhere, so I’m not sure what you’re expecting to happen? What is that variable supposed to be?

Comment: Yes. I have defined it like $s_string = $_GET['q'];

Comment: First things first, you really should be developing with a good debugging tool like XDebug that will allow you to step through your code line by line. Alternatively, try adding  `error_log( $_GET['q'] );` and check your PHP error log to see what the value of `$_GET['q']` is.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the `$_GET['q']` param is set?
Try:

```
$s_string = ( isset($_GET['q]) && !empty($_GET['q']) ) ? sanitize_text_field($_GET['q']) : '';
```